# How to prevent queued event callbacks from firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In jQuery, I have something like this:

```
$( "body" ).on( "touchmove", function() { ...do something expensive });
```

I have noticed that when rapidly dragging my finger around, the callbacks pile up, and often take time to complete even after I have stopped dragging by a few seconds.

Is there a way to cancel callbacks that have not yet fired?  I have tried the following:

```
$( "body" ).on( "touchend", function() {
  $( "body" ).off( "touchmove" );
});
```

...however this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do several things, but please be cautious using `body` for delegated events as 'body' will not respond if the styling is set incorrectly (`document` is more reliable).

**1) Disconnect/reconnect when complete:**

```
var doSomethingExpensive = function(){
  // Disconnect event
  $( "body" ).off( "touchmove" );
  ...do something expensive
  // Reconnnect event handler
  $( "body" ).on( "touchend", doSomethingExpensive)
};

$( "body" ).on( "touchend", doSomethingExpensive);
```

**2) Use a busy/guard flag**

```
var busy = false;
$( "body" ).on( "touchmove", function() { 
    if (!busy){
      busy = true;
        ...do something expensive 
      busy = false;
    }
});
```

**3) Use a plugin that throttles the events**

Basically you specify how frequently it can fire and it wrap code similar to one of the above, but based on a timer. (I have no specific recommendations, suggest Googling it).

**The easiest of these options is probably the guard flag, It is simple and obvious what is going on.**